# Setting page load timeout in Selenium Python binding

Tags: python, selenium, dom, html, bots

I am writing a bot using Python with Selenium module.When I open a webpage with my bot, since the webpage contains too many external sources than dom, it takes a lot to get all of the page loaded. I used the explicit and implicit waits to eliminate this problem since I just wanted a specific element to be loaded and not all of the webpage, it didn't work. The problem is If i run the following statement:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('somewebpage')
elm = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'someelementID'))


elm.click()
```

It doesn't work since the Selenium waits for the driver.get() to fully retrieve the webpage and then, it proceeds further. Now I want to write a code that sets a timeout for driver.get(), Like:

```
driver.get('somewebpage').timeout(5)
```

Where the driver.get() stops loading the page after 5 secs and the program flow proceeds, whether the driver.get() fully loaded webpage or not.

By the way, I have searched about the feature that I said above, and came across there:

[Selenium WebDriver go to page without waiting for page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455210/selenium-webdriver-go-to-page-without-waiting-for-page-load)

But the problem is that the answer in the above link does not say anything about the Python equivalent code.

How do I accomplish the future that I am searching for?

Answer (score 6):

`python` equivalent code for the question mentioned in the current question ([Selenium WebDriver go to page without waiting for page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455210/selenium-webdriver-go-to-page-without-waiting-for-page-load)):

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('webdriver.load.strategy', 'unstable')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

and:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a ton of questions on this, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9161773/742390). Here is an example that waits until all jquery ajax calls have completed or a 5 second timeout.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
```

Answer (score 3):

It was a really tedious issue to solve. I just did the following and the problem got resolved:

```
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
driver.get('somewebpage')
```

It worked for me using *Firefox* driver (and *Chrome* driver as well).